# Invalid python syntax while using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code:

```
produk = soup.find_all("div","col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 bt-product-list")
i = 1
for p in produk:
    print p.find('div','bt-product-list-info').get_text()
    print p.find('div','col-md-3 col-xs-12 bt-product-list-price')
```

This returns the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-1db13187c15e>", line 4
    print p.find('div','bt-product-list-info').get_text()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: which python you are using?

Comment: @Yogi Dwinanto if you're using python3, use `print(p.find(...))` instead of `print p.find(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using Python 3, in which `print` is a function rather than a statement. You would need to modify your code to look like this:

```py
produk = soup.find_all("div","col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 bt-product-list")
i = 1
for p in produk:
    print(p.find('div','bt-product-list-info').get_text())
    print(p.find('div','col-md-3 col-xs-12 bt-product-list-price'))
```